# Multiple view binding with knokcout in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, templatebinding

I have a View xyz.cshtml

in which i render two partial views `a` and `b` . Now in  `xyz.cshtml` page i have a button to switch view . But problems comes when i change view it doesn't apply binding on newly loaded view .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Some code to demonstrate your issue would probably be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the partial views dynamically (I mean if they aren't both loaded on page load, but instead requested on button click) then Knockout will have 0 knowledge of those bindings.

Off the top of my head I would basically have two view models and when you click the button and a new partial view is loaded in run `ko.applyBindings` on the loaded in markup.

Comment: By default template / Partial View `a` is loaded ,

Comment: can we do it by template binding in knockout , like if i close both partial view in script tag make them template . Will this work or not ?

Comment: @user2413182 I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you mean. Regardless of what method you choose if you are adding markup/html (that wasn't just hidden) to your page that has bindings on it you will get no functionality from knockout unless you apply bindings to that new markup/html.

Comment: ok , just tell me that , suppose i loaded a view and applyBinding on that and that works fine after that i append another view in the same body and want to applyBinding on new view . Can i do this ?

Comment: I don't see why not. Should be fairly easy if each view that you append has a unique id that you can reference when applying the bindings.

Comment: ok thanx i got it , got answer of my question . Thanx again